# How to determine pH of food in order to avoid unsuitable storage containers

Tags: ph, metal, food-chemistry

In an acidic (lemon-containing) sauce I had placed a metallic spoon. A few days later it had a metallic taste.

Stainless steal might be a significant source of nickel, chromium and iron [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1514841). Also, using aluminum utensils and packaging when cooking or storing food can contribute to the daily aluminum intake [<sup>[2]</sup>](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8249476).

I want to avoid storing food in metallic containers which could increase my intake of metals.

The pH of some foods can be found [here](http://www.foodscience.caes.uga.edu/extension/documents/FDAapproximatepHoffoodslacf-phs.pdf), but in some cases it's not of much use (when the food is a varying mixture of ingredients).

Is there an easy way to determine the pH of food? (whether the food is colored like a tomato sauce or transparent)

Comment: Well, foods with acidic pH would be acidic to the taste.

Comment: Why not to use indicator paper? http://www.kruuse.com/en/ecom/Forbrugsartikler/Forbrug_lab/Indikatorpapir_forbr/prod_290590.aspx

Comment: @JaroslavKotowski Because many foods are already colored. I imagine it would be hard to distinguish color changes caused by pH from changes caused by food color.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I don't think our tongue is that accurate. As an example honey has 3.70 - 4.20 which to me is quite unexpected.

Comment: mix food, add a bit water, filter a few milliliters and measure pH od the permeate

Answer (score 1):

You can try wetting the tip of an ordinary pH paper, then put it into a sample of your food with that wet side. The capillary forces will suck up the liquid of your food and you should see a colour change in the formerly wetted area and above.

PH paper is not a very reliable method, but it should give you a general idea and it is easily performed at home.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use indicator paper. If you are worried that food coloration will make color determination impossible, you can analyze only sample.

you can take a sample of the food and mix it in a blender. Add a bit of water and filter the mixed sample using filter paper or activated carbon. Then analyze the permeate using indicator paper.